# How can i store data from check-box to Firebase in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-layout

I want to add data from the checkbox to the firebase database in Flutter, how can I do this? see the below code, in case of form field we take controller but in checkbox how can I take data from it ?, in code everything is fine but i got stuck in this line

```
_databaseReference.child("resources").child("Yas").set({
    //what should i code here !!
});
```

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class TestDart extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  TestDart({this.title});
  @override
  _TestDartState createState() => _TestDartState();
}

class _TestDartState extends State<TestDart> {
  final _databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Testing"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Exercise(
              title: "Yash",
            ),
            Exercise(
              title: "Deepak",
            ),
            Exercise(
              title: "Yashwant",
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 25,
            ),
            Container(
              child: Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 55,
                  width: 150,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _databaseReference.child("resources").child("Yas").set({
                        //what should i code here !!
                      });

                      Navigator.pushReplacement(
                          context,
                          PageTransition(
                              child: SubmitPage(),
                              type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft));
                    },
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                    child: Text("Submit",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Exercise extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  Exercise({this.title});

  @override
  _ExerciseState createState() => _ExerciseState();
}

class _ExerciseState extends State<Exercise> {
  bool selected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(widget.title),
      trailing: Checkbox(
          value: selected,
          onChanged: (bool val) {
            `setState`(() {
              selected = val;
            });
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Boolean.
Add this

```
bool flag = false;

RaisedButton(
       onPressed: () {
              setState(){
                  !flag;
                }  
      _databaseReference.child("resources").child("Yas").set({
                            'enabled': flag,
                      });
```

Comment: this will give only true or false value, but questions is stored the value

Comment: Do you mean the label value?

Comment: yes I want to store selected value like Deepak pr may be Yash